# Buscar tablas que contengan dos campos en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero realizar una consulta a una DB donde me muestre las tablas que contienen dos columnas que son: 'notes' y 'name'. Realice la consulta que se muestra mas abajo pero me muestra solo las tablas que tienen la columna 'nombre' o la columna 'name'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (COLUMN_NAME LIKE'name') OR (COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'notes') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='db_prueba';
```

Comment: querras reemplazar OR por AND?

Comment: Si cambias el `OR` por un `AND` debería funcionar. Tu mismo te respondes al decir: *me muestra solo las tablas que tienen la columna 'nombre' **o** la columna 'name'*

Comment: Pero lo que quiero es que me muestre las tablas que tienen estos dos campos, es decir que la tabla tenga la columna 'name' y la columna 'notes'.

Comment: Tienes mal la sentencia del `LIKE`, esta buscando por palabra exacta. Prueba con `LIKE '%name%'` y `LIKE '%notes%'`

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que te muestre las tablas que tienen ambas columnas, `name` **y** `notes`, la consulta seria de esta forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_prueba'
AND (COLUMN_NAME = 'name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'notes') 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
;
```

Si quieres que te muestre las tablas que tienen alguna de las columnas, `name` **o** `notes`, la consulta seria de esta forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_prueba'
AND (COLUMN_NAME = 'name' OR COLUMN_NAME = 'notes') 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
;
```